# multiple table result in single query

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from multiple table with single query.
example :

TABLE-A:

```
|  LOT  |  ITEM  |  QTY  |
--------------------------
|  001  |  PAPER |  20   |
|  002  |  INK   |  10   |
|  003  |  PEN   |  25   |
--------------------------
```

TABLE-B:

```
 |  LOT  |  ITEM  |  QTY  |
 --------------------------
 |  001  |  PAPER |  20   |
 |  002  |  INK   |  10   |
 |  003  |  PEN   |  25   |
 --------------------------
```

TABLE-C:

```
|  LOT  |  ITEM  |  QTY  |
--------------------------
|  001  |  PAPER |  20   |
|  002  |  INK   |  10   |
|  003  |  PEN   |  25   |
--------------------------
```

when I select LOT 001 from all tables, I want the result is :

```
| TABLE NAME | LOT | ITEM | QTY |
---------------------------------
|  TABLE-A   | 001 | PAPER|  20 |
|  TABLE-B   | 001 | PAPER|  20 |
|  TABLE-C   | 001 | PAPER|  20 |
---------------------------------
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT T.* FROM(
  SELECT 'TABLE-A' AS TABLE_NAME, LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TABLE-B' AS TABLE_NAME, LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM TABLE_B
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TABLE-C' AS TABLE_NAME, LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM TABLE_C
) AS T 
WHERE T.LOT = '001';
```

Comment: an error occurred "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
SELECT 'TABLE-A' as 'TABLE-A', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_a` where LOT = '001'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE-B' as 'TABLE-B', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_b` where LOT = '001'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE-C' as 'TABLE-C', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_c` where LOT = '001';
```

Comment: result is not my hope : 
LOT | ITEM | QTY
-----------------------
001  | PAPER|  20
----------------------

Answer (score 0):

i was found the query

```
SELECT  'table_a' as 'TABLE NAME', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_a` where LOT = '001'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'table_b' as 'TABLE NAME', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_b` where LOT = '001'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'table_c' as 'TABLE NAME', LOT, ITEM, QTY FROM `table_c` where LOT = '001'
```